# How to convert existing `TypeVar` into Python 3.12's type parameter syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following `TypeVar` declaration:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=RedisCache)


def make_redis_client(c: ReadableContainer, cache_factory: Type[T], db: BffRedisDB) -> T:
    return cache_factory(redis=redis.Redis(host=c[BffEnvData].get_redis_connection_url(), port=c[BffEnvData].get_redis_connection_port(), db=db.value, decode_responses=False))
```

How can I convert it into Python 3.12's new type parameter syntax?

```
type HashableSequence[T: Hashable] = Sequence[T]  # TypeVar with bound
```

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#new-features

I have tried these:

```
type CacheFactory[T] = Type[T] # 1st attempt
type T[T: RedisCache] # 2nd attempt
...
```

For the first attempt, I get the following error: `PEP 695 type aliases are not yet supportedMypyvalid-type`

Does that mean Mypy doesn't support Python 3.12 type parameter syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Correct. `mypy` can *parse* the new syntax, as long as you use Python 3.12 to execute `mypy`, but it has not yet been updated to *understand* the semantics behind the new syntax. See https://gh-proxy.deno.dev/python/mypy/issues/15238 for more information on the effort to upgrade `mypy`.

In the meantime, if you want to use `mypy` to type-check your code, you cannot use the new syntax. Conversely, if you want to switch to the new syntax, you'll have to use another tool (PyRight, for example) which does support the new syntax.

Comment: Thank you. In general, isn't Mypy very slow to keep up with new changes? I have seen PyRight been praised before for its feature set

Comment: I think you're seeing the difference between a volunteer project and one that is (I think) staffed by full-time Microsoft employees.

Comment: So, why would I use Mypy over Pyright?

Comment: That's not a question we can answer.

Comment: @Shuzheng mypy doesn't have the same goals as Pyright. mypy is additionally developed for (1) building complex linting plugins which go beyond the scope of the current typing system, and (2) compilation of statically-typed code to C extensions with mypyc. If you *only* need static typing with idiomatic Python, then Pyright is the right choice. If you need anything more, like being able to lint errors with complex metaclass/decorator abstractions, then pyright quickly falls short.